# ПочтОмат или почтАмат — как правильно?

Tags: орфография, неологизмы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать: *почт**о**мат* или *почт**а**мат*?
Или эта терминология только формируется?

Comment: @Наталья732, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Сегодня эта терминология еще четко не сформировалась. Связано это с тем, что сама такая система еще не получила широкого распространения на российском рынке. В словарях еще этот термин отсутствует. Сегодня существует несколько вариаций этого термина: почтомат/почтамат/постомат/постамат).
На мой взгляд, "почтомат'' наиболее соответствует правилам русского языка, учитывая при этом тот факт, что в русском языке уже закрепились термины с первой частью латинского корня "post"'. Однако пока нет словарной фиксации , говорить о том или ином "правильном" варианте - нельзя. Выбор остается за автором.

Answer (score 3):

Из двух предложенных слов шансы прижиться больше у слова "почтомат", поскольку есть слово "почтамт", с которым "почтамат" конфликтовало бы. Поначалу оно даже наводило бы на мысль об опечатке.

Answer (score 2):

Я за почтамат, а еще вернее - постамат.

Объяснение написания почтомат через соединительную гласную О критики не выдерживает, "мат" здесь не корень, а (в лучшем случае) его осколок. Более того, слово можно считать частичным аналогом недавно ставшего популярным "коронавируса". Сложность в том, что коронавирус - прямое заимствование, а постамат заимствование не слова, а способа словообразования, ранее в русском почти не встречавшегося, но довольно популярного в английском, когда в слово соединяются не сами корни и другие морфы, а их довольно произвольно отсеченное части. В русском подобные образования представлены словами паралимпиада и каратист. В первом случае от корневого морфа "олимпиад" отсечена первая гласная, по втором - от корня карате - последняя.

Почтамат = почта + (авто)мат. Можно, конечно, спорить, чем, собственно, эта конструкция напоминает автомат, но другого разумного объяснения этимологии слова я просто не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

Что такое постомат-постамат? Ящик, отсек, шкаф в который закладывается какой-то предмет, товар. Закладывается он, всё-таки, человеком. Какая тут автоматизация? Поэтому считаю, что правильнее писать постомат, согласно правилам грамматики русского языка. О-соединительная. Соединительной А нет.

Comment: *Соединительной А нет*. Вам знакомы слова сум**а**сшедший, ум**а**лишённый?!

Answer (score -2):

Я соглашусь с теми, кто за то, чтобы писать "почтОмат", поскольку в русском языке все же привычнее видеть именно такое сочетание букв (по аналогии со словом "автОмат").

Comment: авт**о** -- авт**о**мат; почт**а** -- почт**а**мат